# Cumulative Sum of Matrix/xts object on Two Columns in R

Tags: r, matrix, xts, cumulative-sum

I posted a question regarding cumulative sums yesterday, but since this one is a fair bit different I thought I should create a new topic (I also made sure to properly search the forum in case something similar could be used).

I would like to compute the cumulative sum of the inventory of particular IDs (ID `100` in the example below) based on information in two columns of a matrix/xts object. For ease of use, I have added an example code below:

```
a <- c(20,50,30,50,10, 40)
b <- c("100", "200", "300", "100", "100", "100")
c <- c("200", "100", "100", "200", "200", "100")
matrix1 <- cbind(a,b,c)
dim(matrix1) <- c(6,3)
colnames(matrix1) <- c("inventory", "buyer", "seller")
```

When you put this code into R, a matrix given in the following format should show up:

```
inventory | buyer   | seller
20        |  100    | 200
50        |  200    | 100
30        |  300    | 100
50        |  100    | 200
10        |  100    | 200
40        |  100    | 100
```

EDIT: I have changed the letters in the Buyer and Seller columns to numbers so that it works with matrices properly now, sorry!
(Note that since this is an `xts` object there should be a timestamp to the left of the `inventory` column but I left it out since it isn't relevant).

Now, there are three IDs: `100`, `200`, and `300`, and they each buy and sell from each other, where what happens is that the `buyer` gains inventory at each row and the `seller` loses inventory. In addition, if the same ID is in both the `buyer` and `seller` column, then the inventory remains unchanged. For my particular problem, I only care about the cumulative inventory of ID `100` and I don't care about the cumulative inventory of `200` and `300`.

For the example above, this means that in the first row `100` has a cumulative inventory of 20, and in the second row `100` now has a cumulative inventory of -30. Similarly, for the third row, `100` has a cumulative inventory of -60, in the fourth row it has a cumulative inventory of -10, and in the fifth row `100` has a cumulative inventory of 0. For the sixth row, since `100` is in both the `buyer` and `seller` column, the inventory is the same as the fifth column so that it is again 0.

Therefore I would like to obtain a cumulative inventory vector given as `c(20, -30, -60, -10, 0, 0)`

Also, since this is an `xts` object, I'm unsure if this changes anything (although I highly doubt it does change anything, the only thing I have omitted is the fact that there should actually be a timestamp column to the left of the matrix, but I excluded it since it isn't relevant to the question).

Is there a good way of computing the cumulative sum based on two columns and based on individual IDs?

Comment: Answering questions about 'xts'-objects without seeing the output of dput(xts_obj) is very difficult. Saying the index of an xts object is "irrelevant" is just not believable. Please read [MCVE]

Comment: You should also say what the right answer is. I'm guessing from the problem description that 'inventory" is a count and for  "a" result should be `c(20, -30, -60, -10, 0)`.

Comment: @42- Ah ok, in that case I'll just treat it as a matrix for now and convert it to an xts object after that. And yes I would like to have a vector `c(20, -30, -60, -10,0)` :) I will edit my code to include it

Comment: A matrix might not be the best object to store columns with different data types

Comment: @HubertL in my code the letters are actually numbers, but I changed them to letters in this example to try and make things a little bit clearer/easier to understand. But in that case I'll switch it back to numbers then if it's better

Comment: That's a character matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited it to work on either a data.frame or a matrix. Let me know if this works for you.

```
cum.inv <- function(ID, data){
  stopifnot(colnames(data) %in% c("inventory", "buyer", "seller"))
  cumsum(ifelse(data[,"buyer"] == data[,"seller"], 0, 
                ifelse(data[,"buyer"] == ID, as.numeric(matrix1[,"inventory"]), 
                       ifelse(data[,"seller"] == ID, -as.numeric(matrix1[,"inventory"]), 0))))
}
cum.inv(100, matrix1)
#[1]  20 -30 -60 -10   0   0

cum.inv(200, matrix1)
#[1] -20  30  30 -20 -30 -30

cum.inv(300, matrix1)
#[1]  0  0 30 30 30 30
```

Comment: That looks good :) Ideally I'd like to keep it in a matrix form though if possible (since conversions are quite time consuming!). For the data frame code you posted, if I take the new information I added into my original post then does the code change into this? `cum.inv <- function(ID) {
    cumsum(ifelse(df$buyer==ID & df$seller==ID, 0 ,ifelse(df$buyer == ID, df$inventory, ifelse(df$seller == ID, -df$inventory, 0)))) }` ?

Comment: Yes, you add an ifelse to handle if the buyer and the seller are the same. Instead of `df$buyer==ID & df$seller==ID` I used `df$buyer==df$seller`. And conversions don't have to be time consuming! `as.data.frame()` usually is pretty quick.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was a bit busy before. But your edited code is perfect now, thanks a lot for that!

Comment: Actually, if it's not too much trouble I do have one last question: Is there any way to add that vector back to the original matrix without having to use stuff like `cbind()`? Since the matrix I have is quite  large, if it's possible I would like the function to 'fill out' a fourth column in the matrix. I'm trying to modify your code a bit to do that but I'm not having much luck :(

Comment: A fourth column of what? The result of this function is a vector the length of the rows dimension. `matrix1[,"NewColumnName"] <- cum.inv(300, matrix1)` ?

Comment: Ah that's perfect, yes that's exactly what I was looking for :) I can't believe I forgot something so straightforward haha. Thanks heaps for all the help!